# How can one split these kind of rings as a direct sum of minimal ideals

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, field-theory, galois-theory

Let $P = \Bbb Q[x,y,z,u,v]$ and $I$ the ideal generated by: 
$$\begin{cases}
x^5-2x^4+2x^3-x^2+1,\\ x^4+x^3y+x^2y^2+xy^3+y^4-2x^3-2x^2y-2xy^2-2y^3+2x^2+2xy+2y^2-x-y,\\ x^3+x^2y+x^2z+xy^2+xyz+xz^2+y^3+y^2z+yz^2+z^3-2x^2-2xy-2xz-2y^2-2yz-2z^2+2x+2y+2z-1,\\ x^2+xy+xz+xu+y^2+yz+yu+z^2+zu+u^2-2x-2y-2z-2u+2,\\ x+y+z+u+v-2\end{cases}
$$
How can I split $P/I$ as a direct sum of minimal ideals? 
I solved this question using a matrix algebra that is isomorphic to $P/I$ but I want to know if there is a solution using only polynomials.

Comment: Why did you remove the similar question I saw yesterday? As it turns out the discriminant was a square, so your ring was a product of fields.

Comment: As the question was ill posed and the example did not reflect the problem I have I replaced the question as proposed by another user.

Comment: It’s interesting, @i.m.soloveichik, that the previous field was the real subfield of $\Bbb Q(\zeta_9)$.

Comment: First, you should drop $v$ and the last condition off your statement. Second, I ask whether you think that the result $\Bbb Q[x,y,z,u]/P'$ is isomorphic to a bunch of copies of $\Bbb Q[x]/(x^5-2x^4+2x^3-x^2+1$.

Comment: @Lubin Yes I noticed that.

Comment: @Bogaerts  See related issues in the question: Zero-dimensional ideals in polynomial rings

Comment: @Lubin: Those are indeed subrings, but not necessarily ideals and certainly not likely  to be direct summands, so why is this relevant?

Comment: My apologies for imprecise terminology. By “a bunch of fields”, I meant (and should have written) a direct sum of fields. If this is what your ring looks like, then these summands are precisely the minimal ideals.

Comment: @Lubin: Maybe I'm totally confused, but: Take the splitting field of a cubic that has degree $6$,  There are subfields of degree  $3$ generated by the individual roots, is the splitting field then a direct sum of these subfields?

Comment: A field is never a direct sum of proper subfields. The rings in which you want to find minimal ideals are not fields.